# Connectivity to Azure Managed SQL Instance from local SSMS

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have created a Azure managed sql instance. We have peered the vnet of both managed instance and the local VM vnet. Our organization doesnot allow installing Point-to-site vpn on current VM.

Please advice, how can we connect to managed sql instance from on-premises sql server (SSMS).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you try to connect from a SSMS installed on a host located on-premises, on the routing table that is added to the subnet where SQL Managed Instance is deployed, add another route to the routing table for your on premise subnet with next hop Virtual Network Gateway.

Make sure NSG (Network Security Group) rules allow communication between the subnets on port 1433 for this connection.

Please also ensure that you enabled 1433 outbound on the host Windows Firewall, as this will also not be permitted by default.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Alberto. I will let you know the findings.